# Searching for files starting with a specific string

Tags: bash, grep, find

after a data loss on a cluster, I am trying to find binary files that are in the size range of 1.6 to 1.8GB and start with "CDF", i.e. netcdf files. I am trying to use the following command I found here, which I barely understand: https://superuser.com/a/667050/667626

```
find . -size +1600M -size -1800M -type f -exec bash -c 'grep -q "CDF" < <(head -c 3 "$1")' _ {} \; -printf '%p\n'
```

Which returns an error which I also don't understand:

```
find: ./output: Permission denied
```

Also, could you help me find ways to speed up the search, because the file system is huge.
Thanks a lot for any help!

Comment: At face value, `find` may be telling you that `./output` is a file or directory you don't have permission to access.  What is the output of `ls -ld ./output` ?

Comment: Thanks for your response. here's the output. Any way to skip this folder? drwx------ 3 root domain users 2,0K Feb 21 13:12 ./output

Comment: No need. `find` is **already** skipping that directory because you lack permission to read it.